# How to remove the content in column A based on the content in column B?

Tags: r, regex, string, substring

I encountered a problem that may need your kind help, and thanks in advance. Suppose that I have a full text, how can I extract the information for each defendant.

| full_text | d1 | d2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Defendant John was born in 1978, and he was summoned for this case on December 24, 2013。Defendant Tom was born in 1984, and he has a junior high school education。Defendant makes confession。Defendant is on live。 | Defendant John was born in 1978, and he was summoned for this case on December 24, 2013。 | Defendant Tom was born in 1984, and he has a junior high school education。 |

That is, I now have a full text, and I can use the code as below to extract the information for first defendant. Note that here I only extract the first appearance of the sentence start with "Defendant" because the text is really long, and it has other sentences start with "Defendant" that I do not want.

```
df$d1=sub("(。).*", "\\1", str_extract(df$full_text, "Defendant.*。"))
```

However, now, the problem is, how can I extract the information for the second defendant?

My solution is that I first remove the content in "d1" from "full_text", and then extract the "d2" using the same code as above. Thus, I use the following code:

```
df$full_text <- gsub(df$d1, "", df$full_text)
```

However, the full_text does not change at all. Could you please help me figure out the question and find the most easiest way to do this? Many thanks!

Comment: use `str_extract_all` with the pattern `"Defendant[^。]+。"`

Answer (score 0):

```
str_extract_all(df$full_text, "Defendant[^。]+。")%>%
  enframe(value = 'd')%>%
  unnest_wider(d, names_sep = '_')

# A tibble: 1 × 3
   name d_1                                                   d_2  
  <int> <chr>                                                 <chr>
1     1 Defendant John was born in 1978, and he was summoned… Defe…
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, however, the problem is that it seems to extract all the sentences that start with "Defendant" and ends with "。"  For example, if I change the full text to "Defendant John was born in 1978, and he was summoned for this case on December 24, 2013。Defendant Tom was born in 1984, and he has a junior high school education。Defendant makes confession。Defendant is on live。" Then, it will also extract the useless sentences that "Defendant makes confession。Defendant is on live。" Could you please me with it ? Thanks!

Comment: @XinyanLIU That is exactly what you described in your text. eg you used `Defendant .*。` meaning you need everything from defendant to `。`.I simply followed what you had

Comment: Thank you so much. However, when I use the code "str_extract_all(df$full_text, "Defendant[^。]+。")", it seems to also extract the sentence "Defendant makes confession。" and "Defendant is on live。". However, I do not need these two sentences. Could you please help me with it?

Comment: Or, to put it another way, instead of extracting all sentences. I may just need to extract the first two sentences. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: @XinyanLIU you can do a two step. First extract the first two part ie `"^(Defendant[^。]+。){2}"` then use your code to extract the individual parts